# Google fonts dropdown in Options Framework

Tags: options

Is there a way to add a Google Fonts dropdown to the Options Framework panel (http://wptheming.com/options-framework-theme/)

Comment: Please search for it in the framework code and post the relevant parts...

Comment: You have to provide what you've already tried. The answer is currently flagged as "low quality" and suggested to be closed.

Answer (score 2):

Should be very easy since its has a hook right in place so something like,

```
add_filter('of_recognized_font_faces','add_google_fonts_list');

function add_google_fonts_list($defaults){
    //add as many as you want
    $mine = array(
        'Ubuntu' => "'Ubuntu', sans-serif",
        'Lobster' => "'Lobster', cursive",
    );
    return array_merge($mine,$defaults);
}
```

and when you render the css make sure to add the right import ex:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu);
```